# Can I query inside a SQLite Transaction?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using the SQLite3 database system in the Android library.

I need to execute a query during a transaction to see if there is a similar entry already there.  If there is, I have to perform some other logic and adjustments before I add a new row.

Can I execute a query within a transaction and get the result back immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is safe to do so.

Answer (score 6):

The answer should be yes, BUT only if you're doing queries *in the same thread the transaction was started in*. Even if you use the same database connection, queries **fail completely** if performed on different threads when you're inside transaction (despite transaction mode).

Comment: even if WAL is enabled? I don't think so.